# Babel-node doesn't ignore specified files/folder on compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have a Node app using ES6 that I run with the following command `nodemon cluster.js --exec babel-node`.
I also have a `.babelrc` file :

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "ignore": [
        "public"
    ]
}
```

The folder `public` contains front-end files such as html, css and js. But when I edit a JS file within the public folder, `babel-node` compiles my code and I don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's related to [this](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726) bug. Try using `nodemon cluster.js --exec "babel-node --ignore public"`.

Comment: Doesn't work, actually it doesn't even run the server. But I think `--ignore` expects a regex, what is the regex for the files starting by `public` ?

Comment: `public` is a valid regex and shouldn't prevent you server from starting. Can you create an example project so we can take a closer look?